# Should a public Rest Api have CORS enabled by default

Tags: rest, cors, cross-origin-resource-policy

We're providing a small RESTful service. It delivers some json data and is completely protected with basic authentication.

Most of our customers have implemented a small PHP client (or something like this) which fetches data from our servers and provides it to their users.

Now there is one customer who doesn't have an internal backend but is using a plain HTML file with JavaScript instead. The requests are sent directly out of the clients browser to our service.

This of course causes problems in the browser because the request is sent to another url (our server) and the browsers CORS policy is denying the result.

The customer asked us if we could set all the required CORS headers in our service which would solve his problem:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: *
```

Is there any disadvantage or risk if we provide all these headers by default? Would it be a good idea to always provide the headers to public apis?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` adds nothing if you use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards.  Also, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227779/concrete-example-of-how-can-access-control-allow-origin-cause-security-risks/254684#254684

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: *` is invalid. The only valid value for that header is `true`. However, you can omit that header altogether.

Comment: If your service only delivers data, I'd assume that you only need the `GET` method and no `Content-Type` header. Unless it expects `POST` payloads with `Content-Type: application/json`. But I don't see the need for `PUT`, `DELETE` or `OPTIONS`. As @jub0bs already said, basic authentication requires `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization`, not `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Little known fact: Basic authentication requires `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization` (and not `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`) _only_ if the client (and not the browser itself) sets the `Authorization` header.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen See [this CORS playground](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/cors/playground/?prefillForm=1&requestMethod=GET&requestUseCORS=1&preflightStatus=204&preflightAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&preflightAllowMethods=GET&preflightAllowHeaders=Authorization&responseStatus=200&responseAllowOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fjakearchibald.com&requestHeaderName=Authorization&requestHeaderValue=foo) and try to remove `Authorization` from the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` field.

Comment: @jub0bs: Makes sense, because an automatically inserted `Authorization` header is like an automatically sent session cookie.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Yes, that's the idea. If I remember correctly, all credentials that the browser automatically manages work that way.